# I need to fill a textbox from the data selected in a listbox in another form

Tags: forms, ms-access, textbox, listbox

I am trying to make a textbox in one of the forms get data from a listbox in another form. the other form will be a pop-up form of a query that will be launched upon the clicking on the text box. so this is how it goes

1. Form A is open
2. Textbox A is clicked on
3. Clicking on Textbox A opens Form B which has a listbox
4. Listbox value selected
5. Close button in form B pressed
6. Now textbox A in form A should contain the data we selected in the
   listbox in form B

I think it can be done by creating variables (public variables if I am not mistaken) but i am a total newbie and have no idea what code to use.

the thing is, i have several textboxes in the same form which will run the same code and get the value in the textbox from the same form.

Comment: @Saif Where do you see html? This is MS Access

Comment: oh... sorry that's form things get me in the wrong path. really sorry @OverMind

Answer (score 0):

Could this be something like,

```
Private Sub textBoxA_OnClick()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "FormB", OpenArgs:= "textBoxA"
End Sub

Private Sub textBoxB_OnClick()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "FormB", OpenArgs:= "textBoxB"
End Sub
```

Then select the ListBox item you want to. Then on click the button, you could make a small check if item was selected. Then based on that you could put that data into the textbox.

```
Private Sub formBButton_OnClick()
    If Me.FormBList.ListCount = 0 Then 
        MsgBox "You have not made any selection, please select an option.", _
                vbInformation
        Exit Sub    
    End If

    If Len(Me.OpenArgs & vbNullString) <> 0 Then _
        Forms("FormA").Controls(Me.OpenArgs) = Me.FormBList

    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly, that would work, but my problem is, i have several text boxes that are to be filled in the same way. lets say txtboxA,B,C,D, and E and i want the button to fill the textbox that triggered it. using your code, i will have to create multiple forms with the same everything except for the button code. can't i just have one form and this form fills the text box that triggered it?

Comment: In that case employ the control name in the OpenArgs that triggered the open form method. Check my edited code !

Comment: Command works great. but the message box doesn't appear. it just closes the selection form only.

Comment: MsgBox "You have not made any selection, please select an option."

Comment: The message box will appear only if you have not made any selection.

Comment: yes. it does not. even if no selection is made, it doesn't appear

Comment: Have you made sure you are referencing the right List Box?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i used.

I hid all the text boxes and made them invisible.

I added an add button.

Add button opens the form (frmslctattendee)
In the form the value of the combo box is selected from query
Then the code behind the command button is as follows.

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
    If Forms!frmmeetings!txtat8.Visible = True Then
        Forms!frmmeetings!txtat9.Visible = True
        If Len(Forms!frmmeetings!txtat9 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            Forms!frmmeetings!txtat9.Value = cmbnameselect.Value
        End If
    End If

    If Forms!frmmeetings!txtat7.Visible = True Then
        Forms!frmmeetings!txtat8.Visible = True
        If Len(Forms!frmmeetings!txtat8 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            Forms!frmmeetings!txtat8.Value = cmbnameselect.Value
        End If
    End If

    If Forms!frmmeetings!txtat6.Visible = True Then
        Forms!frmmeetings!txtat7.Visible = True
        If Len(Forms!frmmeetings!txtat7 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            Forms!frmmeetings!txtat7.Value = cmbnameselect.Value
        End If
    End If

    If Forms!frmmeetings!txtat5.Visible = True Then
        Forms!frmmeetings!txtat6.Visible = True
        If Len(Forms!frmmeetings!txtat6 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            Forms!frmmeetings!txtat6.Value = cmbnameselect.Value
        End If
    End If

    If Forms!frmmeetings!txtat4.Visible = True Then
        Forms!frmmeetings!txtat5.Visible = True
        If Len(Forms!frmmeetings!txtat5 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            Forms!frmmeetings!txtat5.Value = cmbnameselect.Value
        End If
    End If

    If Forms!frmmeetings!txtat3.Visible = True Then
        Forms!frmmeetings!txtat4.Visible = True
        If Len(Forms!frmmeetings!txtat4 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            Forms!frmmeetings!txtat4.Value = cmbnameselect.Value
        End If
    End If

    If Forms!frmmeetings!txtat2.Visible = True Then
        Forms!frmmeetings!txtat3.Visible = True
        If Len(Forms!frmmeetings!txtat3 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            Forms!frmmeetings!txtat3.Value = cmbnameselect.Value
        End If
    End If

    If Forms!frmmeetings!txtat1.Visible = True Then
        Forms!frmmeetings!txtat2.Visible = True
        If Len(Forms!frmmeetings!txtat2 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            Forms!frmmeetings!txtat2.Value = cmbnameselect.Value
        End If
    End If

    If Forms!frmmeetings!txtat1.Visible = False Then
        Forms!frmmeetings!txtat1.Visible = True
        If Len(Forms!frmmeetings!txtat1 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
            Forms!frmmeetings!txtat1.Value = cmbnameselect.Value
        End If
    End If

    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

it does the job. 
waiting for your comments.

Comment: I am a bit at loss with your code. You are checking for the visibility of one control but setting the value for another control? It seems to be, checking the visibility of Control(n-1), but setting the value of Control(n). How is that even doing the job?

Comment: how it works is that I have locked all the text boxes so users can't interact with it. then when the button is clicked, it checks for the last visible text box then makes the next text box (which is not visible yet) visible and adds the selected info to it. it also adds the info to the last empty text box, otherwise it will put the data to all the earlier textboxes.

Comment: A very long confusing way to a simple problem I'd say. See if the edited code in my answer works for you !

Comment: in my case, it will check for the visibility backwards, from 9 to 1. assuming the first 3 boxes are visible. the If clause will be false for the boxes 9 to 4 and no code is executed. then at text box 3 it will be true and hence it will make textbox 4 visible and add the data to it (because it is still empty). then it will proceed to boxes 1 to 3, and they are true as well, but since they are not empty, it will not add any data to them.

Comment: i suppose it is. that's what my newbie mind could come up with. i will try yours now.

Comment: can i ask about the me.* that i find everywhere. i still don't know what is it used for, and i never used it